# Is there way to use another jmx client than jconsole?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I am introducing with `JMX`. I have wrote simple application which print message in loop.
from jconsole I change value of variable to terminate loop ant this work.

But I don't understand how to use `JMX` in life.

Do usually write own jmx client or use jconsole ?

Comment: jvisualvm with jmx plugin. Connect from java code...

Comment: Can you provide example?

Comment: what how to use jvisualvm?

Comment: how to connect from java code

Comment: It depends on what you actually want to achieve, but is how you do it from java code: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html